# Mysql_moving values from a text column to a numerical column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to move some text values from a column (old_col) to a numerical column within the same table. Some of the text fields show decimals (like 53.00) some don't (e.g. 1435). This is what I tried to do

```
alter table table_name
ADD new_col DECIMAL(10,2)
```

I set decimal(10,2) but I'm pretty sure it's a mistake as I get an error (incorrect decimal value) when I run the following

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `new_col` = `old_col`
```

Comment: What happens if you do `select cast(old_col as decimal(10,2)) from table_name`?

Comment: Then be sure you are moving it as the right type and try `CAST()` ! `UPDATE table_name SET new_col = CAST(old_col AS decimal(10,2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do silent conversion by treating the value as a number:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
    SET `new_col` = `old_col` + 0;
```

Note that strings that are non-numeric will be assigned zero.

Or, you can test the format of the value:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
    SET `new_col` = (CASE WHEN old_col REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$' THEN `old_col` + 0
                     END)
```

This sets invalidly formatted numbers as `NULL`.

Actually, the `case` is silly.  Just use a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
    SET `new_col` = `old_col` + 0
    WHERE old_col REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$';
```

Comment: should be `. . . [0-9]+$` instead of `. . . [0-9]*$`. If not values like `1.` would be treated as valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I needed